# Ошибка 0x80070021 в IIS 7.5 windows 7 - не работает url rewrite

Tags: iis

Нижеописанная ошибка выдаётся при попытке перехода по любому переопределенному url.
Что это за секция такая в конфиге "webFarms" и почему она исчезла (до недавнего времени переопределенные url работали корректно).

*Описание ошибки:*

Ошибка HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error
Запрашиваемая страница не доступна из-за неверной конфигурации данных для этой страницы.

*Подробные сведения об ошибке*

- Модуль   **ApplicationRequestRouting**
- Уведомление  **MapRequestHandler**
- Обработчик   **ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0**
- Код ошибки   **0x80070490**
- Ошибка конфигурации  **Не удалось прочитать раздел конфигурации "webFarms" из-за пропущенного объявления раздела**
- Запрашиваемый URL-адрес  **http://localhost:80/url/**
- Физический путь  **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\url**
- Способ входа **Анонимная**
- Пользователь, выполнивший вход   **Анонимная**
- Файл конфигурации    **\?\C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\DefaultAppPool\DefaultAppPool.confi**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить

```
<section name="webFarms" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
```

В конец

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        ...
        // сюда
    </configSections>
</configuration>
```

Причина постоянного удаления этой секции из конфига не ясна (причем только у одного сайта).